# NFS server Windows 2008 - mounting via linux - input/output error help

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, nfs

I want to try mounting a folder with NFS - I set up the NFS sharing on a windows 2008 R2 server, specified hosts in the NFS permissions (by IP address) and mounted via /etc/fstab

it mounts, but when I try to list the folder, I get 'input/output error'

the owner/group on the local mount point look weird too?

drwx------  2 4294967294 4294967294 4096 2011-02-10 19:15 data/

I mounted in /etc/fstab as:

10.0.6.55:/share$ /media/data nfs soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on the Windows Server side and it could not map the unix account to AD.

This blog post+comments led me to the solution.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sfu/archive/2007/04/19/mounting-nfs-share-on-nfs-client.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the NFS settings in windows NFS Share settings, checking allow Unmapped users access radio box allows it to work.

Answer (score 0):

UID/GID mapping can be messed up, but you could try and chown the mount to yourself

Comment: tried mounting with a specific gid/uid, didnt work.  any other ideas?

Comment: I meant mount as root, and then chown the mount to root

Comment: tried that no luck same issue.

Comment: can you post how you configured the NFS in windows? especially the NFS share screenshots